# Max width in Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am working on a chat app. I want the message (text view) to always start 20px from the left of the screen. When the message is short, the text view's width is wrap content. But when the message is long, the text view will reach 50px to the right of the screen. How to achieve it.

[image: short text]

*short text*

[image]

*long text*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` with `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"`

The following works for me:

```
<TextView
        android:text="sampleskdjfalksfasdkfjakllksdajfkljaskfdlasdjfklajdfklajkf"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:background="#666"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the width 0dp and use left and right guidelines as 20dp and 50dp respectively. Keep the horizontal bias s 0.0 You can use margins also if guidelines are not needed

Comment: If you use width 0dp then short view version won't be wrap_content, which is the requirement in the question